# Tropical charts (coordinates) and differential forms in non-archimedean geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, tropical-geometry, non-archimedean-fields

Chambert-Loir  and  Ducros have  introduced real differential forms and currents on Berkovich spaces.(See Gubler's [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.7364) for example). In that survey, a tropical chart $V$ is defined on an analytification $X^{\mathrm{an}}$, something like $ \mathrm{val}^{-1}(\Delta)$ for a polyhedron $\Delta$. Here $\mathrm{val}: (K^\times)^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is defined by $(z_1,\dots,z_n) \mapsto (\mathrm{val}(z_1),\dots,\mathrm{val}(z_n))$

**Question:**

1. I am an beginner for this subject, I don't understand the reason to use tropical charts, what's the advantage? It seems not so good because they are contained in a torus $(K^\times)^n$ so they exclude zero. But in differential geometry local models are $\mathbb R^n$ which include zero.
2. Let's consider the rigid analytification
   $$\mathbb A_K^{n,rig} = \cup_{i=0}^\infty \mathrm{Sp} K \langle c^{-i}\zeta_1, \dots, c^{-i}\zeta_n\rangle
   $$
   of the affine $n$-space $\mathbb A^n_K=\mathrm{Spec} K[\zeta_1,\dots,\zeta_n]$ (here $|c|>1$). In this case can we find some good tropical charts?
3. Other than the example in the question 2 above, can we explicitly give any other tropical charts? say on the Berkovich projective line?

Comment: I don't undestand what do you mean in 2. by tropical charts on a rigid space, if it is not a Berkovich space. Do you mean the associated Berkovich space or do you want an analogous notion in a rigid space?

Comment: I think I mean the associated Berkovich space. By the way, do you mean tropical charts can only be defined on Berkovich spaces rather than rigid spaces?

Comment: I am not sure how one can define "tropical charts" on rigid spaces, since the tropicalization maps are not in the appropriate category.

Comment: About your first question, I really don't understand what's your problem. You should think that the valuation($=-log(|\ |)$) is not defined on 0, so you cannot include it.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I mean, I don't have a good intuition for the tropical chart. For example, smooth manifolds locally are $\mathbb R^n$. But here Berkovich space (or rigid space) locally have to exclude zero, this makes me feel confused. Why not use local model like $K^n$ as in differential geometry

Comment: To understand Berkovich spaces start first with the analytic projective line, also called the witch's broom. See for example the notes of Matt Baker in his homepage.

Comment: I know Baker's note. So, for example, can you find a tropical chart on the Berkovich projective line which cover the point $0$ or $\infty$ or the Gauss norm?

Comment: You choose two points $a,b\ne 0, \infty$, and take the open set $U=\mathbb P^{1 an}\setminus \{a,b\}$. You can map $U$ to $\mathbb Gm^{an}$ by the analytic (in fact algebraic) bijective morphism $f(z)=(z-a)/(z-b)$. Now, tropicalization map $v:\mathbb Gm^{an}\to \mathbb R$ defines $U$ as a tropical chart.

Comment: @Xarles Thank you very much! So, if we put $b=\infty$ then your argument can give a tropical chart on $\mathbb A^{1~an}-\{a\}$ by the map $f(z)=z-a$. But I find it hard to generalize this to higher dimension as in my problem 2, do you know how to do so or any reference? Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to explain what it is a tropical chart on an algebraic variety over a non-archimedean field $K$ (complete with respect to a non-archimedean absolute value, algebraically closed by simplicity).

First of all, for the algebraic tori (of the form $T:=\mathbb G_m^n$, for $n\ge 1$), we have a continuous map $Trop\colon T^{an}\to \mathbb R^n$, where $T^{an}$ is the Berkovich analytic space associated to $T$, usually called the tropicalization. Then in Gubler's notation, the preimage $V$ for $Trop$ of any open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^n$ is a tropical chart of $T$.

Now, for any algebraic variety $X$, consider affine open subsets $U$ such that there is an closed immersion to an algebraic torus $T$ (they are called **very affine**). For this open affine subsets there is in fact a canonical closed immersion to a torus $ \varphi_U\colon U \to T_U$.

Note that any algebraic variety can be covered by very affine open sets, refining the usual covering by affine open sets.

Now, a tropical chart $(V,\varphi_U)$ is an open subset $V \subset X^{an}$ contained in a very affine subset $U$ such that $V=\varphi_U^{-1}(Trop^{-1}(\Omega))$ for an open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. Using that the very affine open sets are a basis for the Zarisky topology, one can show that the tropical charts are a basis for the analytic topology of $X^{an}$ (see the Proposition 4.16).

So **any** algebraic variety has a covering by tropical charts, hence **any** Zarisky open set of an algebraic variety.

Compare with the usual analytic charts, where a chart can be seen as $(V,\varphi_U)$, with $V\subset X^{an}$ and $U$ an open subset with a map $\varphi_U\colon U\to \mathbb C^n$ such that $V=\varphi_U^{-1}(\Omega)$, for $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb C^n$.

The fact that here we have $\mathbb G_m^{n,an}$ instead of $\mathbb A^{n,an}$ (which should be the natural analogue of $\mathbb C^n$) is a quite interesting question; it happens in several place in the non-arquimedean world (e.g. Tate elliptic curves).

Comment: By an algebraic variety, I follow "Serre's convention": https://mathoverflow.net/a/7798/24442.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a great answer. I take some time to digest. But I still feel confused about one point: people usually consider $Trop^{-1}(\Delta)$ for a rational polyhedral $\Delta\subset \mathbb R^n$. (See Einsiedler-Kapranov-Lind's paper for example). In this case, it is simple and is given by an affinoid algebra. But here a tropical chart is defined for an arbitrary $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$. When $\Omega$ is **not** a rational polyhedral, what can we say? I even don't know if $Trop^{-1}(\Omega)$ is still a Berkorvich space.